# how to remove the union type refinement of of inherited type with undefined in TypeScript or Flow

Tags: typescript, flowtype

I have a typing that I had inherited and am importing from a library and I was wondering how I can go about removing its allowance for null or undefined values.

```
type Foo = {
    baz: string
}

// Bar type is inherited and I would like to kill the union with undefined so I expect foo to never be falsey.
type Bar = {
    foo?: Foo
}
const bar: Bar = {foo: {baz: 'baz'}};
// this destructuring issues an error because it allows for the possibility of it being undefined and undefined can't be destructured. And I can't conditionally exit since I'm using React hooks and I'd be violating the hooks should not be used conditionally rule
const {baz} = bar.foo;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a utility type in built in typescript called [Required](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#requiredtype), you can use it like below

```js
type Foo = {
  baz: string
}

type Bar = {
  foo?: Foo
}

type StrictBar = Required<Bar>
// type StrictBar = { foo: Foo } inferred
```

Comment: awesome! is there a similar tool for Flow? the issue was actually a Flow issue and I was hoping that there were a tooling-agnostic solution.  Thanks again!

Comment: after seeing the link, I saw the equivalent for Flow here: https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-nonmaybe